# XMLParser content "\f" Interrupt

Tags: ios

I am running the following code

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@<xml><p>%@<\p></xml>",@"abcd\f1234"];
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
```

```
delegate func

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
NSLog(@"%@",string);//result is abcd  Why not is abcd\f1234
}
```

If string is `<xml><p>1234<\p></xml>` `foundCharacters` output `1234` if string content `\f` output result is wrong.

Why is the returned content not the entire paragraph? Please help me！

Comment: `NSInputStream *readStream = [[NSInputStream alloc]initWithFileAtPath:path];
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithStream:readStream];` stream read file will also interrupt if content `\f`

Comment: Is `\f` a legal string in xml content?

Comment: The content is sent by the server.